# Is there a versatile engine to translate JavaScript object into a different object?

Tags: templates, object, datatemplate, jsrender, jsviews

I'm looking for a versatile way to translate a big object into a custom object using a template. It should be able to traverse `each` value of arrays, and reference parent values in the loop.

Imagine an object like:

```
{
    collectionId : 432,
    products : [
        {
            productId : 1155,
            suppliers : [
                {
                    supplierId : 252,
                    supplier : 'SupplyCompany',
                    shipments : [
                        {
                            date : 'foo',
                            order : 'bar',
                            id : 45
                        },
                        {},
                        {},
                        //...
                    ]
                },
                {},
                {},
                //...
            ]
        },
        {},
        {},
        //...
    ],
}
```

I would for example want to flatten this into:

```
[
    {
        collectionId : 432,
        productId : 1155,
        supplierId : 252,
        supplier : 'SupplyCompany',
        date : 'foo',
        order : 'bar',
        id : 45
    },
    {},
    {},
    //...
]
```

Right now I'm using manual `for` `for` `for` loops, but this isn't very versatile when the source object changes or one of my output objects change. It's not very maintainable to 'hardcode' these translations.

There are templating engines that do something resembling what I want, e.g. [JsRender](https://github.com/borismoore/jsrender). It theoretically allows you to do what I need:

```
{{for products}}
    {{for suppliers}}
        {{for shipments}}
            collectionId : {{:#parent.parent.parent.parent.data.collectionId}}
            productId : {{:#parent.parent.parent.data.productId}},
            supplierId : {{:#parent.parent.data.supplierId}},
            supplier : {{:#parent.parent.data.supplier}},
            date : {{:date}},
            order : {{:order}},
            id : {{:id}
        {{/for}}
    {{/for}}
{{/for}}
```

(This is pretty nice because [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) doesn't allow you to do this.)

However, jsRender reads strings (templates) and output strings (html). The overhead from all the `stringify` and `parse` is not doing any good in my case.

I'm looking for something that does this kind of processing with objects. From objects to objects.

Comment: You should have a look at [softwarerecs.se] (they probably do require you to reformat the question slightly, e.g. including MSCW type requirements may help, be sure to check their FAQ), it's better suited for asking for library recommendations.

Comment: Apart from that, have you considered using plain [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)?

Comment: I considered that, but I found it doesn't increase the versatility or readability over iterating using `for`. It even makes referencing 'parent' objects harder than using plain `for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do that kind of thing using JsRender. For example it is really easy to create custom tags, converters, etc. (or use helper functions) and make them have side effects of mapping objects to some output object. Of course the philosophy of JsRender is generally to be declarative, without side effects, but if you want to you can indeed use it a 'processor'.

Here is a [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/8d49e3ad/) which can give you some ideas:

It uses a custom tag:

```
$.views.tags({
  addObject: function(target) {
    var item = $.extend({}, this.tagCtx.props);
    target.push(item);
    ...
  }
})
```

and a template:

```
{{for products ~collectionId=collectionId}}
    {{for suppliers ~productId=productId}}
        {{for shipments ~supplierId=supplierId ~supplier=supplier}}
            {{addObject ~target collectionId=~collectionId productId=~productId supplierId=~supplierId supplier=~supplier date=date order=order id=id/}}
        {{/for}}
    {{/for}}
{{/for}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Do you have any insights about `~` versus `#parent.parent` concerning processing overhead when iterating, say, 5000 objects?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you could detect any difference. Passing in contextual template parameters is more maintainable (if you modify the templates later), and syntactically cleaner. The memory or perf cost should be small. (Worst case you can make some tests to compare...)